# Запятая: «в-главных» и «в-последних»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, и

Нужна ли запятая?

`В-последних(,) я хочу сказать, что я устал.`

`И в-главных(,) этот кот нипочём не ест брюссельскую капусту!`

Comment: я хочу сказать, что устал. Я устал - уже точно излишество.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В орфографическом словаре:
[**в-последних**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85), **в-главных** — это вводные слова, которые в указанных предложениях нуждаются в обособлении.

• ***В-последних,** я хочу сказать, что я устал.*
(Лучше, думаю, без повторов "я": Я хочу сказать, что устал. Хочу сказать, что я устал.)

*Во-вторых, зачем-то посереди огромный аквариум. Quel cauchemar! **В-последних,** кухня кавказская. Не трактир, а духан какой-то!* (Авдотья Ипполитова. Гамбургер по-старорусски).

• ***И в-главных,** этот кот нипочём не ест брюссельскую капусту!*

> **6.** Между присоединительным союзом (в начале самостоятельного предложения) и вводным словом (сочетанием) запятая обычно не ставится, так как союз тесно примыкает к вводному слову: <...> ***И главное,** не забудьте приложить аннотированную библиографическую карточку...*

Вводное слово "в-главных" чаще используется в таких сочетаниях: *во-первых  и в главных, во-вторых и в-главных, в-третьих и в-главных ...*

***В-четвёртых и в-главных,** Волкодаву трудно было заставить себя поверить однажды разоблачённому обманщику* (Мария Семенова. Волкодав: Знамение пути).

[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122) (Розенталь)

Comment: в-главных и в-последних - такие кривые слова... но в словаре Виноградова они таки значатся.

Comment: Ну... Кривые не кривые, а в орфографическом словаре тоже имеются.

Comment: Quelle réponse magnifique!